# Anchor with already anchored page?

Tags: html, css

First allow me preface, I know very little about html, CSS, etc. Most of what I can do is by following other examples. I am doing a header menu, and each link is an anchor within the page. (the div are hidden until clicked) However I became stuck on this problem. I have link within page as follows:

```
<div class="header">
    <a href="#B1">Block 1</a>
    <a href="#B2">Block 2</a>
</div>
```

This will give me url `"localhost/test1.html#B1"`. However, one of the div blocks contains this:

```
<div id="B1">
    <a href="#slide-one">
    <a href="#slide-two">
</div>
```

So I already figured out I can't do `"localhost/test1.html#B1#slide-one"`.

I don't know if its possible to even do this anchor link to page that is already opened as anchor. No option to use any jquery, flash, java, etc. I can only use HTML/CSS. I am going to assume this is not possible, but I thought one last attempt to try this and ask here.

EDIT:
Updated sample code provide better explanation:

```
 <style type="text/css">
div#Menu {
  height:90px;
  left:0;
  position:fixed;
  top:-5px;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}

div#B1 {
  position:absolute;
  left:-1000px;
  margin-top:0;
}
div#B1:target {
  top:100px;
  left:375px;
}

div#B2 {
  position:absolute;
  left:-1000px;
  margin-top:0;
}
div#B2:target {
  top:100px;
  left:375px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<!--Header Menu-->
<div id="Menu" class="header">
    <a href="#B1">Block 1</a>
    <a href="#B2">Block 2</a>
</div>



<div id="B1" class="blocks">
    <div id="Slider1" class="Slide">
        <ul>
            <li id="slide-one"><img src="slide-one.png"/></li>
            <li id="slide-two"><img src="slide-two.png"/></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#slide-one">Slide 1</a>
        <a href="#slide-two">Slide 2</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="B2">
    <div id="Slider1" class="Slide">
        <ul>
            <li id="slide-three"><img src="slide-three.png"/></li>
            <li id="slide-four"><img src="slide-four.png"/></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#slide-three">Slide 3</a>
        <a href="#slide-four">Slide 4</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I have are CSS image sliders with thumbnail navigation that are anchors within each section. On the menu I go to block #1 which opens  which contains one image slider gallery. My page url changes to "test1.html#B1" The image slider has anchor for each image.

On a separate normal page the slider alone would give page url for each image something like "test1.html#slide-one".

But this is nested, and the image slider is child to "B1" block. I need to have the block #B1 opened, and AFTER that has opened on page I have the image slider gallery. That has its own anchors for each image, but I need "B1" to remain.

Comment: One anchor will 'replace' the other. What are you hoping to have happen with two unique elements "targeted" at once? Store state for the page? With just HTML/CSS, targeting an element by ID causes the page to scroll to cause that element to be visible. I assume you don't imagine that is possible with two different ones.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

From how your question is expressed we can think of two different needs:

1. Since you said you're wanting to do `localhost/test1.html#B1#slide-one` it could mean that you consider `#slide-one` exists not only in the "context" of `#B1` but also elsewhere (say in `#B2` for instance): but if this happens it means that `#B1` and `#B2` are not in the same HTML page! So it cannot be what you're wanting.
2. At the opposite, the whole rest of your text indicates that all the parts you want to reach are in the same page. So it's the case I'will explain below.

When in the same HTML page, it can't be several `id`s with the same value: **an `id` is unique**, by design.
The consequence is: to target a given `id` you have no need of several intermediate points, even if the user really used these intermediate points like in your example.

In summary, the code you showed in your question is perfectly enough!

Last point: if an `id` is always unique, at the opposite you can have an unlimited number of occurrences where you target it. In other words, the same (unique) destination can be pointed to from several `<a>`.